# Name the function $f(x,y) = f(x,0) + f(0,y)$

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a function $f(x,y)$ where $x \in R$, $y \in R$ and $f \mapsto R$.

What would you call this function when I add these properties to $f$:

- $f(x+r,y) = f(x,y) + f(r,0)$
- $f(x,y+r) = f(x,y) + f(0,r)$

for any $r \in R$

Comment: Consider $g(x)=f(x,0)$ and $f(x+r,0)$. Can you find the form of g(x)?

Comment: A line.  So each component of $f$ is linear?  Can one just say that $f$ is linear?

Comment: Assume that the form of $g(x)$ is known.  If it helps, assume that it is linear.

Comment: Is there any connection between the title and the actual question?  When you write $f(x+r,y) = f(x,y) + f(r,0)$ for any $r,$ do you also mean it is true for any $x$ and $y$, or only for a particular pair of numbers $x$ and $y$?

Comment: For any $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I have a guess - is it a _linear map_?

Answer (score 0):

I found the name that I can use.  The concept called *linear map* is what I was looking for.

To use the term, I am happy to include the homogeneity condition to my list

- $f(cx,cy) = cf(x,y)$ for any $x$, $y$ and $c \in R$

(Thanks for guiding me in the right direction)